# Is there nothing to scan for in the Ninmah Cluster?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have had access to the Ninmah Cluster for a while now after doing some mission there. I have been around scanning a couple of times now between mission with out any luck. For all other areas where I can get Reaper attention there has been something to scan.

Is there nothing there or am I missing it over and over again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It's empty, I'm afraid.** [Others such as yourself](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/995452-mass-effect-3/answers?qid=316015) had found themselves also searching in vain, so do not feel alone in your frustration.

Comment: +1, it's very odd that you can still draw Reaper attention inside Maskim Xul. It led me on to think that there was something still there.

Answer (score -2):

No there are no assets in the ninmah cluster. They will most likely add assets in future DLCs.